# What is ok in questions about writing comics?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I'm wanting to start a comic. I know I can ask questions here about the words part of writing,  but what about questions of conveying meaning without words?

Like, recently, I was looking for info about how one, two, and three-point perspective affects the feeling in a reader, noting how different comic writers use it in clearly deliberate ways. This didn't feel like the right place to ask, but it felt better than any other Stack Exchange site.

I ended up with answers a different way, but I'm sure other questions will come up. Some about writing with words, some about other writing. Is this the place for the latter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd be fine with it. You are still crafting a story, creating characters and relationships, unfolding a plot, even with imagery added to words. It's not about film-making, which is an entirely different medium. I don't think we have a ComicsSE, so as long as your question is about the storytelling (your POV example is a good one), I would consider it on-topic.

Comment: Was gonna write much the same thing. I'd even say that questions here can be about telling the story through the visual elements, as long as it's in a way that's about the story and not the medium or the execution.

Comment: I agree with Lauren and Neil. Questions about, say, pen/brush technique would be over the line IMO, but visual storytelling is still storytelling.  Please ask!

Answer (score 5):

Just as scripts written for movies are writing and on topic here, scripts for comics are writing and on topic also.

I'd only guess that most of us aren't very familiar with writing comics, but I've drawn a few, and I might go and dig up my copy of *The DC Comics Guide to Writing Comics*.